# spark aws throwing java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, httpclient, aws-sdk

we are using standalone cluster for Spark 2.4 version. we need to upgrade AWS SDK version to 1.12.654 (not ready to AWS V2 yet) and because of that we upgrade to hadoop 3.1.1. After facing lot of issues with dependencies , we are stuck with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error which we are unable to figure it out.

exception is

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.http.HttpResponse.getHttpRequest()Lcom/amazonaws/thirdparty/apache/http/client/methods/HttpRequestBase;
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3ObjectResponseHandler.handle(S3ObjectResponseHandler.java:57)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3ObjectResponseHandler.handle(S3ObjectResponseHandler.java:29)
    at com.amazonaws.http.response.AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.handle(AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.java:69)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1794)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleSuccessResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1477)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1384)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1157)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:814)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:781)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:755)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:561)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:541)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5520)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5467)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.lambda$reopen$0(S3AInputStream.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.reopen(S3AInputStream.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.lambda$lazySeek$1(S3AInputStream.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.lambda$retry$2(Invoker.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.lambda$retry$3(Invoker.java:260)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:210)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.lazySeek(S3AInputStream.java:321)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.read(S3AInputStream.java:433)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.fillBuffer(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.readLine(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.initialize(LineRecordReader.java:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.<init>(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.<init>(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.TextInputCSVDataSource$.readFile(CSVDataSource.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$2.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$2.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:132)
```

when we look at the jar versions we have S3ObjectResponseHandler is from  aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.654.jar calling HttpResponse which is from aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.654.jar.

when i look at imports in HttpResponse class it has

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
```

so that class seems to be from HttpClients dependency but the exception is thrown at `com/amazonaws/thirdparty/apache/http/client/methods/HttpRequestBase` which i found it in aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.654.jar . i am not really sure how to fix it. i have excluded httpclients from dependency, try to force using aws-java-sdk-bundle. its been a week i am stuck. not sure what i am missing.

any pointers would be appreciated.

update.

i see in aws bundle pom file below.   i am guessing because of it showing the package name as com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http ,
when exception is throw. but still i am not sure why that method is not found, when aws bundle is in class path

```
<relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>org.apache.http</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

hadoop-aws uses "aws-java-sdk-bundle" jar as its dependency to avoid problems with inconsistencies within the aws artifacts. Do the same.

see: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws

Recommend upgrading to the 3.3.6 release of hadoop too, for all hadoop-* JARs too.

Comment: We have removed Aws Bundle from classpath, than the spark job started throwing errors related to dynamo db. My spark job dont have any integration with dynamo, so not sure why, but anyways we added aws dynamo dependency and now it is working. end of day its working with lots of trail and error but we dont know the reasons for those errors, why it started working after removing bundle.

Comment: you need the full aws bundle *and nothing else from aws sdks*